# Method is defined twice

Tags: scala

Why scala REPL does not allow to have several function with same names inside another function?

```
  def wrapper(): Unit = {
    def a: Unit = ???
    def a(i: Int): Unit = ???
  }
```

> error: method a is defined twice
>
> conflicting symbols both originated in file '< console>'

Comment: It's a somewhat arbitrary (but common) decision. Turns out debugging gets tough if you do this (and it is difficult to imagine why you would want it).

Comment: My function is something like this getBirthDates(userData: UserData){
 isValid(month: String) = month.matches(regexp) && isValid(month.toInt)
 isValid(month: Int) = month > 0 && month <= 12 
...
} And now I moved them as private methods of the object.
But actually I've been coding on scala for 2 years and never found this issue before, so it is a rare situation.

Comment: Does this happen only in the REPL or also when compiling your source code as usual?

Comment: I found it in Idea, but Idea often does not compile valid code so I tried in REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use overloading (OOP feature) inside a method what is not proper OOP primitive for that and it is not looks resonable from OOP point of view (and I agree with compiler). To align this with OOP features, just wrap it in object:

```
def wrapper(): Unit = {
  object wr {
    def a: Unit = ???
    def a(i: Int): Unit = ???
  }

  wr.a(10)
  wr.a
}
```

Comment: Good idea, also I can add import wr._ and use just a(10)